# i want to apply gmail api to send invitation request to contacts on that id?

Tags: c#

Actually I am searching for a gmail api to send invitation request to the contacts on that 
account.

I am applying but i am not getting the proper result.

Give me the proper API which can work properly.

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Answer (score 0):

Read this
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/limits
There can be some limitations, so its good to find some third party api

try this if suits your requirement
https://www.prefinery.com/api/v2/docs/friend_invitations